# Finding Links on a Webpage with Java

Tags: java, regex, hyperlink

Using Java have the source code of a webpage stored in a string. I want to extract all the urls in the source code and output them. I am awful with regex and the like and have no idea how to even approach this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: protip: do not parse html with regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Don't use regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Use a [parser](http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers) like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/).

```
String html = "your html string";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html); // Can also take an URL.
for (Element element : document.getElementsByTag("a")) {
    System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/), then to extract the links it's as simple as:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
URL url = new URL("http://www.oogly.co.uk/");
HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) wc.getPage(url);
PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(FILE_NAME));
List anchors = page.getAnchors();
```