# Retrieving URL's from webpage in java

Tags: java, http, web

I have the most basic java code to do a http request and it works fine. I request data and a ton of html comes back. I want to retrieve all the url's from that page and list them. For a simple first test i made it look like this:

```
int b = line.indexOf("http://",lastE);
int e = line.indexOf("\"", b);
```

This works but as you can imagine it's horrible and only works in 80% of the cases. The only alternative i could come up with myself sounded slow and stupid. So my question is pretty mutch do i go from

```
String html
```

to

```
List<Url>
```

?

Comment: Same question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717760/finding-links-on-a-webpage-with-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pattern p = Pattern.compile("http://[\w^\"]++");
Matcher m = p.matcher(yourFetchedHtmlString);
while (m.find()) {
   nextUrl=m.group();//Do whatever you want with it
}`

You may also have to tweak the regexp, as i have just written it without testing. This should be a very fast way to fetch urls.

Comment: That gives me the invalid escape sequence exception

Answer (score 1):

I would try a library like [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) to parse the html string and extract all url tags from it.

Answer (score 0):

Your thinking is good, you just missing some parts.

Yous should add some known extension for urls.
like `.html` `.aspx` `.php` `.htm` `.cgi` `.js` `.pl` `.asp`

And if you like images too then add `.gif` `.jpg` `.png`

I think your doing it the best just need to add more extensions checking.

If you can post the full method code, i will be happy to help you make it better.

Comment: The problem is that a lot of links don't end in an extension like index.php?page=here